# How to Display Foreignkey data in view file?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have a relation between the `project` and `skuoption` table, my `skuoption` table has a `product_id` table, but I am unable to display `skuoption` data on my view page, please check my code and let me know where I am mistaking.

Here is my `models.py` file...

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=225)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=225, unique=True)
    brand=models.ForeignKey('Brand', related_name='product_brand', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    supplement= models.ForeignKey('Supplement', related_name='product_supplement', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    subcategory=models.ForeignKey('SubCategory', related_name='prosubcat', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and here is `skuoption` table code...

```
class SkuOption(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    variantflavour=models.ForeignKey('Flavour', related_name='varflavour', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    variantsize=models.ForeignKey('Size', related_name='varsize', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    sku=models.CharField(max_length=285, null=True, blank=True)
    price=models.CharField(max_length=285, null=True, blank=True)
    qty=models.CharField(max_length=285, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sku
```

Here is my `product-view.html` file, where I am displaying data from `product`, `brands`, and `skuoption` table...

```
<div class="product-right">
                        <h2 class="mb-0">{{product.name}}</h2>
                        <h5 class="mb-2">Brand: <a href="javascript:void()">{{product.brand.brand_name}}</a></h5>
                        <h5 class="mb-2">Supplement Type:  <a href="/supplement-type/{{product.supplement.supplement_slug}}">{{product.supplement.supplement}}</a></h5>
                        <h4><del>₹ {{product.totalprice}}</del></h4>
                        <h3>₹ {{product.variant.name}}</h3>
                        <ul class="color-variant">
                            <li class="bg-light0">Display `price` here from `skuoption` tble</li>
                            <li class="bg-light1">Display `sku` here from `skuoption` tble</li>
                            <li class="bg-light2">Display `qty` here from `skuoption` tble</li>
                        </ul>

    </div>
```

please display any value here (`<li class="bg-light0">Display price here from skuoption tble</li>`) from `skuoption` table

Comment: {%for sku in product.skuoption_set.all %}{{ sky.price }}{%  endfor %}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
  <ul class="color-variant">
 {% for sku in product.skuoption_set.all %}
     <li class="bg-light0">{{sku.price}}</li>
 {% endfor %}
     </ul>
```

Comment: it's working perfectly, but when I am fetching data in for loop then `variantsize` and `variantflavour` are repeating, I want something like this, if `size` is `small` then it should be displayed once on mine website.

Comment: what is `skuoption_set`, and where it is coming from...

Answer (score 1):

method 1:
If you are using **models.Foreignkey** in your skuoption class which is Many-to-One relationship. It means **Many objects of your SkuOption** table related to **One Product object**.
So for example,
if you want to get Skuoption of a product having id = 1
{app}/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render , HttpResponse
#import your models 

def home(request):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=1)
    context = {'product':product}
    return render(request, 'app/home.html', context)
```

and template/home.html will be like

```
<div class="product-right">
  <h2 class="mb-0">{{product.name}}</h2>
    <ul class="color-variant">
       {% for sk in product.skuoption_set.all %}
         <li class="bg-light0"> {{sk.sku}}</li>
         <li class="bg-light1"> {{sk.price}}</li>
         <li class="bg-light2"> {{sk.qty}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
     </ul>
  </div>
```

notice forloop here. as we are using many to one relationship(ForeignKey)
**.skuoption_set.all**  gives you all the objects related to a product. Then we can
use **" . "** operator to access values.

**note : This method will give all the rows of skuoption of the product. This may not be the suitable method for it.**

method 2:
If you are using **models.OneToOneField** in your skuoption class which is **One-to-One relationship**. It means only **One object of your SkuOption table** related **to One Product object**.

considering the above example
views.py file will be same
changes in templates/home.html

```
<div class="product-right">
  <h2 class="mb-0">{{product.name}}</h2>
     <ul class="color-variant">
        <li class="bg-light0">{{product.skuoption.sku}}</li>
        <li class="bg-light1">{{product.skuoption.price}}</li>
        <li class="bg-light2">{{product.skuoption.qty}}</li>
      </ul>
 </div>
```

You can access any one to one related table with **.** operator like this
*[primarycalss].[relatedclass].[field]*

**note: All model class name should be in lowercase while using in templates**